# HTML parsing issue in Racket

Tags: html, parsing, racket

I want to parse some HTML documents, it seems that Racket's html and xml library can't handle this very well. For example, here's an HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <script>
            var k = "<scr";
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Neither `read-html` nor `read-xml` can parse this. They think the `<scr` in `var k = "<scr"` is part of an opening tag.

So, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [html-parsing](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=html-parsing.plt&owner=neil) package.

> The html-parsing parsing behavior is permissive in that it accepts erroneous HTML, handling several classes of HTML syntax errors gracefully, without yielding a parse error. This is crucial for parsing arbitrary real-world Web pages, since many pages actually contain syntax errors that would defeat a strict or validating parser. html-parsing’s handling of errors is intended to generally emulate popular Web browsers’ interpretation of the structure of erroneous HTML. We euphemistically term this kind of parse “pragmatic.”

Although I don't know for sure if it will handle `<script>` tags like this, it might. The author, Neil Van Dyke, is active on the [Racket mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html).

Comment: According to http://planet.racket-lang.org/package-source/neil/html-parsing.plt/2/0/planet-docs/doc/index.html, HtmlPrag is obsoleted. [html-parsing](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=html-parsing.plt&owner=neil) seem to work.

Comment: @EFanZh Sorry for the confusion. I updated my answer with the link to the newer version of that package by the same author.